# Removing a black part of image after stitching 2 images in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So I stitched 2 images in OpenCV C++ but I know have a full black part in the image and would like to remove it. What would be the way to go?

Here is my image output:

[image]

Comment: The first thing would be to write some code that people could give input on. Right now, there are two pictures only. What could anyone say about those? Make a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note:*** *According to nathancy's answer I just coded using C++:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("/your/image/directory/image.jpg");

    for(int i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
    {
        int black_cnt = 0;
      for(int j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
      {
         if(img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]==0)
             black_cnt++;
      }
      if(black_cnt==img.rows)
          continue;
      else
      {
          Rect roi(i,0,img.cols-i,img.rows);
          img = img(roi);
          break;
      }
    }    
    imshow("Result",img);        
    waitKey(0);        
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: tested this code, and it has no effect of the stitched image

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to sum the pixels of each column then iterate through the data to construct the new image. If the value of a column is zero then it means it is black so we ignore it otherwise we concatenate the column ROI to the final image. Here's the summation of the column pixels:

[image]

Result

[image]

I implemented it in Python but you can adapt a similar idea to C++

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load image, convert to grayscale, and sum column pixels
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
h, w = image.shape[:2]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
first_pass = True
pixels = np.sum(gray, axis=0).tolist()

# Build new image
for index, value in enumerate(pixels):
    if value == 0:
        continue
    else:
        ROI = image[0:h, index:index+1]
        if first_pass:
            result = image[0:h, index+1:index+2]
            first_pass = False
            continue
        result = np.concatenate((result, ROI), axis=1)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
# Uncomment for plot visualization
# plt.plot(pixels, color='teal')
# plt.show()
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast way to do it is to use `cv::reduce` function of OpenCv and find maximum value per column. It is faster than making sum of elements. If max value in column is 0, it means that column is black.

Input of `cv::reduce` is 2d-array:

```
[a b c]
[d e f]
[g h i]
```

as output will get matrix 2d with one row - vector.

```
[max(a,d,g) max(b,e,h) max(c,f,i)]
```

Then you need to find cutOff index - first non-black column, and extract ROI:

```
cv::Mat img = imread("test.jpg");
cv::Mat out;
cv::reduce(img, out, 0, cv::REDUCE_MAX);
int cutOffIdx = 0;
for (int col = 0; col < out.cols; ++col) {
    const cv::Vec3b& vec = out.at<Vec3b>(0, col);
    if (vec[0] || vec[1] || vec[2]) {
        cutOffIdx = col;
        break;
    }
}
cv::imshow("test",img(cv::Rect(cutOffIdx,0,img.cols-cutOffIdx-1,img.rows)));
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

- Thresholding the graysclae image
- Finding the outermost contours in the image
- Find the biggest one from the contours
- Get the bounding box of that contour
- Crop the image by that bounding box

[image]

And the code (C++ opencv):

```
Mat K,J,I = imread("D:/1.jpg",1);

cvtColor(I, K, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(K, J, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;

findContours(J, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE); # Gives the outer contours

Mat tmp = Mat::zeros(I.size(), CV_8U);
int k = 0;
double max = -1;

for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) # Of course in this case, There is only one external contour but I write the loop for more clarification
{
    double area = contourArea(contours[i]);
    if (area > max)
    {
        k = i;
        max = area;
    }
}

drawContours(tmp, contours, k, Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1); # You can comment this line. I wrote it just for showing the procedure
Rect r = cv::boundingRect(contours[k]);

Mat output;
I(r).copyTo(output);

imshow("0", I);
imshow("1", J);
imshow("2", tmp);
imshow("3", output);
waitKey(0);
```